# MKPointAnnotations touch event in swift

Tags: swift, view, mapkit, mkpointannotation

I would like to know if anyone can tell me how I can touch a pin on the `map` in the form of `MKPointAnnotations` .

I would like to click the `pin` on the `map` and go to another view by bringing back the `variables` of the `pin` that I have preset .

Can anyone explain me this thing in `Swift` ?

thanks

Edit with code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var mappa: MKMapView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.648590, longitude: 10.918794)

    let pinAnnotation = PinAnnotation()
    pinAnnotation.setCoordinate(location)

    self.mappa.addAnnotation(pinAnnotation)

}

class PinAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    private var coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get {
            return coord
        }
    }

    var title: String = "test"
    var subtitle: String = "test"

    func setCoordinate(newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coord = newCoordinate
    }        
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if annotation is PinAnnotation {
        let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")

        pinAnnotationView.pinColor = .Purple
        pinAnnotationView.draggable = true
        pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
        pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

        let deleteButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        deleteButton.frame.size.width = 44
        deleteButton.frame.size.height = 44
        deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "trash"), forState: .Normal)

        pinAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton


        return pinAnnotationView
    }

    return nil
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
    if let annotation = view.annotation as? PinAnnotation {
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If the annotation's title is blank, callout will not display when you tap on it.

Comment: I added the annotation , and a written text , the popup comes out properly but does nothing .. you know why?

Comment: Maybe the map view's delegate outlet is not connected/set.

Comment: I confirm that it is connected, more than anything else , I wonder where I match the method MapView , are new to the language and can not understand how he can leave this method if you do not call ... thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Several steps are necessary, here are some code snippets to get you started.

First you need a custom class for your pin annotation which holds the data you want to work with.

```
import MapKit
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PinAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    private var coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    private var _title: String = String("")
    private var _subtitle: String = String("")

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get {
            return coord
        }
    }

    func setCoordinate(newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coord = newCoordinate
    }   

     var title: String? {
        get {
            return _title
        }
        set (value) {
            self._title = value!
        }
    }

    var subtitle: String? {
        get {
            return _subtitle
        }
        set (value) {
            self._subtitle = value!
        }
    } 
}
```

Then you need a custom class for your `MKMapView` which conforms to the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol. Implement the method `viewForAnnotation` there:

```
import MapKit
import CLLocation
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    ...

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
        if annotation is PinAnnotation {
            let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")

            pinAnnotationView.pinColor = .Purple
            pinAnnotationView.draggable = true
            pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
            pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

            let deleteButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            deleteButton.frame.size.width = 44
            deleteButton.frame.size.height = 44
            deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            deleteButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "trash"), forState: .Normal)

            pinAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton

            return pinAnnotationView
        }

        return nil
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
        if let annotation = view.annotation as? PinAnnotation {
            mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
```

That gives you something like this:

[image]

To add a new annotation to your map use this somewhere in your code:

```
let pinAnnotation = PinAnnotation()
pinAnnotation.setCoordinate(location)

mapView.addAnnotation(pinAnnotation)
```

Comment: Hello , in viewDidLoad to load the point on the map as the septum ?
I can not figure out how to tell the map to add the pin

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to add a new pin to the map.

Comment: I edited my question with my code , now I see the pin on the map , but if I click does nothing , no tooltip appears , how do I fix ?

Comment: It is called automatically because it is a delegate function. Make sure the your custom class is set as the mapview's delegate.

Comment: I set the delegate of MKMapView pointing to my ViewController , I have also extended the class , as you can see in the above code .

What else have I forgotten? the method does not automatically MapView

Comment: Do you have a trash image as in my example? If not, remove the code which creates the leftCalloutAccessory and see if it works.

Comment: yes yes I put the picture , my problem is that the method does not automatically MapView , I dragged the delegates of mkmapview ... added to the controller extension class and even costresso it with self.maps.delegate = self .... at this point I do not know what to do :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort you 've marked the question right , I made ​​some changes and now goes

Answer (score 5):

Greate work !!! BUT..
I just copy past this and I had to add a few changes. I'll share with you guys those changes.

```
import MapKit
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PinAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
private var coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
private var _title: String = String("")
private var _subtitle: String = String("")

var title: String? {
    get {
        return _title
    }
    set (value) {
        self._title = value!
    }
}

var subtitle: String? {
    get {
        return _subtitle
    }
    set (value) {
        self._subtitle = value!
    }
}

var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    get {
        return coord
    }
}

func setCoordinate(newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.coord = newCoordinate
}
}
```

I hope it will help :D