# How do you add information to location maker on Xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm super new to Xcode and swift - I was wonder what the coding would be for adding information to a location marker, where that "i" is, and what would I have to do to make sure that when the user taps on the icon, information will pop up?

[image]

Comment: Possible a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123724/swift-adding-a-button-to-my-mkpointannotation.
What you're looking for is `rightCalloutAccessoryView`.